# Сгенерировать звук определенной частоты в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я хочу создать простейший метроном. Не знаю как сгенерировать звук определенной частоты. Помогите, кто знает. На самом деле задача такая, частота отстукивания должна изменяться каждую минуту, например в первую минуту 70 ударов в минуту, следующую минуту 90 ударов в минуту и т.д. Но, с алгоритмом я и сам справлюсь, а вот как сгенерировать звук не знаю.

Comment: http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

Comment: записать звук, воспроизводить с помощью тега audio, а управлять повтором через `javascript`. Или генерировать свой звук как по ссылке выше

Comment: На самом деле хорошая статья, я бы отметил как ответ на вопрос